# How can I read the firebase's uid as a normal display name?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have this register Method:

```
onSubmit(){

  this.authService.doRegister(this.email.value, this.password.value)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.errorMessage = "";
      this.successMessage = "Your account has been created";
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
      this.errorMessage = err.message;
      this.successMessage = "";
    })
  }
```

Service:

```
doRegister(email, password) {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(res => {
          resolve(res);
        }, err => reject(err))
    })
  }
```

And then a display list where I wish to  associate the post with the actual name of the person instead of this userId

```
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <mat-list role="list" *ngFor="let post of posts">
            <mat-list-item role="listitem">Title: {{post.title}}</mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item role="listitem">Body: {{post.body}} 
</mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item role="listitem">By: {{post.userId}}</mat-list-item>
                     </mat-list>
        </div>
      </div>
```

How can I accomplish this? I have read plenty of dead end posts saying its not possible. Is it?

Comment: Email/password auth doesn't have the user's real name immediately available for display.  You have to prompt the user for their name, then update their user profile.  After that, the name will be available after they sign in.

Comment: Ok @Doug Stevenson , thanks for the info but can you point me a tutorial or a post regarding this?